# Opera - really weird font issue

Tags: wordpress, fonts, opera

So I am developing a wordpress theme and I am using the Google fonts plugin. I am using only OpenSans font, with 300 for headlines and 400 for text weights.

Everything works perfectly, except for Opera. For some reason, the first time you load a page, it uses 400 font-weight for everything, including headlines. However, if you reload a page with F5, it then uses correct font-weights.

I've tried to remove all font-weights from CSS, remove 400 font-weight from that plugin, yet, no results. It seems like Opera is ignoring the font-weight property the first time a page loads - making h1 - h8 fonts bold - and only applying it after page reloads.

Any clues what to do?

Comment: Can you share a test case? Also, which version of Opera are you seeing this problem with?